# Multiprocessing is not working when extracting data from list of urls in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I am trying to extract data from list of urls stored in local text file. The code is running perfectly but very slow, so i applied Multiprocessing as below mentioned.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from multiprocessing import Pool

filepath = open('d:\links.txt', 'r')

allnames = list()
alltitles = list()

def extractm():
    for ii in filepath:
        geturl = requests.get(ii)
        soup = html.fromstring(geturl.content)
        names = soup.xpath("//dt[contains(text(),'Corresponding Author')]//following::dd//text()[1]")
        titles = soup.xpath('//body//title//text()')
        for (name, title) in zip(names, titles):
            allnames.append(name)
            alltitles.append(title)
            fullfile = pd.DataFrame({'Names': allnames, 'Title': alltitles})
            writer = ExcelWriter('D:\\data.xlsx')
            fullfile.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
            writer.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pp = Pool(10)
    pp.apply_async(extractm())
    pp.close()
    pp.join()
```

Even after applying Multi process it is running same like before, please any one help me on this.

Comment: a lot of issues in the above approach. It should be completely rewritten

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, kindly guide me how it should be written, i have never used Multiprocessing

Comment: I need to realize the input data and the expected result beforehand for that

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest,
https://www.omicsonline.org/use-of-cooled-radiofrequency-lateral-branch-neurotomy-for-the-treatment-of-sacroiliac-joint-mediated-low-back-pain-2329-9096.1000161.php?aid=19992
https://www.omicsonline.org/neurostimulation-and-chronic-pain-management-2329-9096.1000e105.php?aid=19991
https://www.omicsonline.org/cardiac-sarcoidosis-ffdgpetct-as-the-most-helpful-tool-in-the-decision-making-of-medical-management-and-assessment-of-response-to-treatment-2161-105X.1000160.php?aid=19982

above are some urls and i would like to extract name, title (xpaths are in question)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, and i need to store the data in Excel file